# DevOps permissions: Is there a way to grant project-level permission for iterations and areas but not allow for project security?

Tags: security, permissions, azure-devops-server

I am configuring a project for a team in Azure DevOps (server).

I would like to allow some members of that team to create/manage their own iterations and areas but I can't seem to do so without granting them permission to the project's security. Even where the permissions are inherited, the user can still add/remove people from the security groups.

Do all three permissions truly come from the "Edit project-level information" setting or is there something else I can do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have since learned that being a member of "Project Administrators" is what grants access to manage security, not the "Edit project-level permissions" setting.